# How to add a session time-out function in Android 's program?

Tags: android

I'm new in android.I want to know how to add a session time-out function in a program for Android? like using website ,if you have no action in one hours ,the page will remind and log out.how to realize this in Android application?thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe AlarmManager is what you want.

To schedule an alarm:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, <trigger time>, <the intent>);
```

To cancel an alarm:

```
am.cancel(<the intent>);
```

Comment: can someone elaborate how to do this? I mean what to put in the intent part? :(

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a similar functionality in my app.
For that I used the SharedPreferences to save the LoginTime of the user.
Furthermore I implemented a backgroundservice which checks the login time each 20 seconds.
The login in my case expires after 30 minutes. 
After that the SharedPreferences LoginTime is cleared and my app returns to the LoginActivity.
Well, I don't know if that is the best way to do this and that is a very basic explanation. But it works excellent for me.